# popup doesnt show with img loaded from json

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm programming a web application in particular front-ending side using JavaScript, AngularJS, HTML and CSS (for an univeristy project) and that's my issue:

I loaded on my js file, a JSON (the result of a query) as

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter'])

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

 $http.get('json/painting.json')
   .then(function(res){
        $scope.paintings = res.data;
    });
```

but it doesn't work in my application.

If I create the scope in this way

```
$scope.paintings = [
  { 
     title: 'title1', 
     picture: 'img/397x300/01.jpg', 
     desc: 'Image01', 
     technique: 'acquerello', 
     dimension: '50x50',
     year: 1800, 
     artist: 'Picasso' 
  },
  { 
     title: 'title2', 
     picture: 'img/397x300/02.jpg', 
     desc: 'Image02', 
     technique: 'aereografia', 
     dimension: '70x50', 
     year: 1700, 
     artist: 'Paolone' 
  }
];
```

in my HTML I call it using the angular function to show a popup on clicking the pics

```
div class="work work-popup-trigger" ng-repeat="paints in paintings 

img class="pics" src="{{paints.picture}}"
```

with the first one it doesn't work, but I can't use the second because it loads data locally and I would like to use JSON for the PostgreSQL interaction.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to look at what is in `res`. Is it a string or an object? Does it have a `data` property? What is in that property? Are you sure it's an array? Basically, you need to debug your application.

Comment: i tried to load the scope as 

$http.get('json/painting.json').then(function(res){
        $scope.paintings = [{id:res.data[0].id,dimension:res.data[0].dimension,picture:res.data[0].picture}] }); 

and it seems the scope is not visible as scope , but pics get loaded same in my view !